# javascript trouble with nested if

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, nested, match

I am trying to input strings queries and from them use string.match to pick out necessary information to perform metric conversions.  After a good deal of experimenting, I keep getting this as output:
"There are 0 inches in null centimeters"

I am wondering if there is something wrong with the logic in my if statements.  Here is an example of one:

```
    var metric = string.match(/centimeters|liters|grams/);
    var english = string.match(/inches|quarts|pounds/);
    var ind = string.indexOf(metric);
    var ind2 = string.indexOf(english);

   if (string.match(/centimeters/) && string.match(/inches/)){
        if (ind < ind2) {
            var string = document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var num = string.match(/\d+$/);
            parseInt(num);
            var conNum = num * 2.54;
            document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "There are " + conNum +  " centimeters in " + num + " inches.";
        }
        if (ind2 < ind) {
            var string = document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var num = string.match(/\d+$/);
            parseInt(num);
            var conNum = num/2.54;
            document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "There are " +           conNum +  " inches in " + num + " centimeters.";
            }
```

Comment: What are the strings that you're feeding to this code?  It looks like it expects strings of the form `inches centimeters 5` - is that right?

Comment: I was trying to take strings in the form of "How many inches are in 3 centimeters"

Comment: Also I just tried changing it to
if (string.match(/centimeters/) {
...}
and then it performed the calculations correctly

Comment: Well your number-matching regex explicitly requires that the number come at the very end of the string - that's what `$` means in a regular expression.

Comment: i just removed the $ and it works correctly now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not actually 100% sure what you want, you haven't told where the initial `string` comes from, so I am assuming some stuff:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="box1" value="10" />
<div id="unit"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var string = 'centimeters to inches'

    var metric = string.match(/centimeters|liters|grams/);
    var english = string.match(/inches|quarts|pounds/);
    var ind = string.indexOf(metric);
    var ind2 = string.indexOf(english);

   if (string.match(/centimeters/) && string.match(/inches/)){
        if (ind < ind2) {
            var string = document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var num = string.match(/\d+$/);
            parseInt(num);
            var conNum = num * 2.54;
            document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "There are " + conNum +  " centimeters in " + num + " inches.";
        }
        if (ind2 < ind) {
            var string = document.getElementById("box1").value;
            var num = string.match(/\d+$/);
            parseInt(num);
            var conNum = num/2.54;
            document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = "There are " + conNum +  " inches in " + num + " centimeters.";
            }
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fw5ubvo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Things to note:

- The `.match()` method returns an array, not a string. Your code will work because your regular expressions don't include any groups, but I'd fix that anyway.
- Calling:

  ```
  parseInt(num);
  ```

  will have no effect on anything. That alone, however, will not hurt, because you use `num` with `*` or `/` operators, and that will convert the string (which comes from the array, again) to a number anyway. It will not however force the value to be an integer.
- Your number matcher regular expression insists that the numeric part of the input string is at the end of the string. That's what the `$` means. Thus, the only expressions in which numbers will be found will be strings like `inches centimeters 5`.